# PANDAS: Is there a natural way to get the value of a cell in the previous row given the current row and col?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
    a   b   c   d
A   1   6   4   1
B   2   6   3   9
C   1   2   4   5
D   4   6   1   5
```

Id like to provide the row name, the column name, and a number of rows to shift back. Then I'd
like to know what value is in that cell.

For example:

```
df.ix[C,b] & shiftback= 2 rows
```

Would return:
    6

Is there a super fast way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, you want a function that takes a dataframe, a location (row and column) and a number right? You'll want to use pandas shift method.

```
def f(df, row, col, nshift):
    return df.shift(nshift).loc[row, col]
```

Works with negative numbers too. You may want to handle shifts that would put you outside differently; this will return `NaN`s.

```
In [12]: f(df, 'C', 'b', 2)
Out[12]: 6.0
```

Also by fast, did you mean performant or short and simple? This is short but probably not that performant.

Comment: ``df.ix[df.index.get_loc('C')-2,'b']`` will be much faster (as it doesn't shift anything, just an index lookup)